# Converting nvarchar to float

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have columns `datefield` and `amount` but `amount` is of type `nvarachar` in SQL Server.

I'm getting an error when I try to sum or convert the `amount` column.

I tried this simple one:

```
Select creationdate, sum(Cast(amt AS float)) 
from table name
```

In that data I have null values and negative and positive values also.

I would like to sum negative and positive values.

But I'm getting conversion error

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to include your table definition(s), your exact SQL, some sample data, the output you want, and the output you are getting. That will allow the community to replicate your problem and help you. Thanks.

Comment: Clearly you have some bogus or unexpected data.   Use try_convert() instead.  If the conversion fails, it will return a NULL and not throw an error.   To resolve you data issue.      Select * from YourTable where try_convert(float,YourCol) is null